# How to create polyline of varying distance from origin point using azimuth?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, linestring, azimuth

I am looking for a Python script that does the following:

1. Uses a point (from a point shapefile) as the origin.
2. Creates about 3 km line from point
3. Based on an azimuth provided in the original point shapefile.
4. Creates new entry in another shapefile with the new line

I imagine this involves trig, but I can't decide the best way to go about it.

Comment: Closely related: [code showing how to create shapes based on point locations, distances, and bearings](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31294).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may not have to get too sophisticated--ArcGIS 10 has a tool to do just what you describe called [Bearing Distance to Line (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000ts000000).  You can even input a point shapefile as long as it has the attributes you need (i.e. X field, Y field, Distance Field, and Bearing).  Of course you can add this tool to an arcpy script using:

```
arcpy.BearingDistanceToLine_management(in_table, out_featureclass, 
     x_field, y_field, distance_field, {distance_units}, bearing_field, 
     {bearing_units}, {line_type}, {id_field}, {spatial_reference})
```

[image]