# Find arc endpoint with bearing and radius counting with curvature of the earth?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spherical-geometry

So my problem is that I have start point [lat,long] for arch, bearing, radius and I need compute end point [lat,long] ? End point should be in 180 degrees angle from start point and I should be aware of curvature of the earth ... So let say I have start point [54.01,104.05], bearing is 170 and radius is 2 km ... Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a circular arc? Anyway, since you say the endpoint is at a 180° bearing, doesn't your problem simplify to a linear distance addition/conversion (lat+2*R)?

Comment: The `goto` function in the code at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31401 shows how this can be calculated for a spherical datum.  However, for a 2 Km arc you don't need to worry about the earth's curvature!

Comment: Add tags navigation and bearing to your question

Answer (score 1):

Charles Karney provides tools and code for navigating on ellipsoids in geographiclib

https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/1.49/